# dynamic form fields changing with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

Hy! i am new to web development and just stuck at a point. I have a form at which 2 fields are generated by one drop down menu. Now the problem is I have generated one field and trying to get another field but due to lack of knowledge I am stuck. I just need little bit help if someone can

```
<form name="myform">
    <select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
        <option value="1">Directory Submission</option>
        <option value="2">Articale Submission</option>
        <option value="3">Social Bookmarking</option>
        <option value="4">Blog Commenting</option>
        <option value="5">Forum Submission</option>
        <option value="6">Link Building</option>
    </select>
    No. Of Submissions: <select name="opttwo" size="1">
        <option value=" " selected="selected">Select any option of the above first</option>
    </select>
    Amount Payable:
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="amount" onchange="document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value;" />
```

Now my javascript is this:

```
function setOptions(chosen) {
    var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
    selbox.options.length = 0;
    if (chosen == " ") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
    }
    if (chosen == "1") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('100 Directory Submission', '$9.99');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('100 Directory Submission', '$9.99');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('300 Directory Submission','$29.99');
    }

    // and like this other options will come too.
}
```

I just want to know that how th field of amount payable will get the amount.

Comment: call an ajax function onChange of the first field , and let this ajax retireve the data for next field , set data from ajax to the second field

Comment: I must first point out that your HTML code is incorrect: you have to close the `<form>` element *before* closing the `<td>`, or wrap the entire table in the `<form>` element.

Comment: What do you want to do in the input field? this is not doing anything  `onchange="document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value;" `

Comment: I just want to print print amount in that field. it did alert on submit and that is ok but it is not giving me value into input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7bQee/)

```
function setOptions(chosen) {
    var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
    selbox.options.length = 1; // no need to delete the first option
    if (chosen == "1") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('100 Directory Submission', '$9.99');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('100 Directory Submission', '$9.99');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('300 Directory Submission','$29.99');
    }
    document.myform.amount.value="";
    // and like this other options will come too.
}​
```

with this code

```
      <select name="opttwo" size="1" onchange="this.form.amount.value=this.value;">
        <option value=" " selected="selected">Select any option of the above first</option>
      </select>
      Amount Payable:
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" name="amount" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: your code is right and I also want something similar to this but its not working properly. I want to know that how the amount which is something like this $34.99 or $19.99, how it will show in my text field?

Comment: Sorry, I put the onchange on the option instead of the select.